# How to use tab keys to focus in an input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `table` with `td`'s that if double clicked, become `input` fields. Now, I want to jump from an `input` to another.

I already made this to change my `td` to an `input`:

```
var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("cell_id").text();
var html = $(this).text();
var input = $('<input id="txt_id" type="text"/>');
input.val(html);
$(this).html(input);
```

And this to jump from one to other:

```
$("#mainTable").on("keydown","td.mainCellQuantity",function(e) {
      var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

      if(keyCode==9||keyCode==13){
       e.preventDefault();
       var cellIndex = $(this).index();
       $(this).closest('tr').next().children().eq(cellIndex).dblclick();
      }
});
```

The above codes are working but the `input`'s are not focused. I want them to be focused after tab press.

```
var rows = parseInt(document.getElementById("my_table").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].rows.length);
var table = document.getElementById("mainTable").getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];

var row = table.insertRow(rows);


var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

cell1.innerHTML = editable_cell_being_transformed_to_input;
```

I want this `cell1` to be focused since upon double clicked, it only change the `td` to `input` but not focusing: [image: this image shows what i want]

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML as well so that your code can be tested......

Comment: You don't need any JS for this, tabbing between form fields is default behaviour.

Comment: I have similar type of example on [JSFiddle][1]


Hope, this will be help you http://jsfiddle.net/shoesheill/30Ls8kty/1/

Comment: Guys, my end statement was actually what I want: "The above codes are working but the input's are not focused. I want them to be focused after tab press." I already found a solution about tabbing, I just want the inputs to be focused after tab

Comment: @Mamun I am dynamically creating rows, see updates for the code

Comment: I also added image for clarification of what I really want

Answer (score 1):

An alternative: Instead of replacing `td` with `input` you can set `contenteditable` attribute to `true` for each `td`. This allows editing the `td` content. Also pressig **Tab key** moves focus to next `td` by default.

Example:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true">data 1</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">data 2</td>
    <td contenteditable="true">data 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```